# PHP DOMDocument replace content by div id

Tags: php, domdocument

I am trying to repalce content of div like in jQuery .html(). This is what I have done so far:

```
$html = "
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="text">
                <p>This is some text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
";

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
// change div id "text" contents
// $("#text").html("<p>This is some new text</p>");
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code, you just need to change the `nodeValue`

```
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$doc->documentGetElementById('text')->nodeValue = "<p>This is some new text</p>";
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Isn't it getElementById rather than documentGetElementById?

Comment: And this won't work, as <p> will be translated into a string and will be shown as "<p>" in the output. You need to create a dom-node and assign it into it.